# Mostrando somente pares na lista - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Meu código precisa **mostrar um número int maior que 2 e precisa imprimir a sequência de números pares menores que ele mesmo e precisa começar do zero**.

Caso seja menor que 2 tem que imprimir `Invalid number`

Exemplo:

```
Entrada = [20]
Saída = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Meu código (não está em execução):

```
seqpair = input("Type a number pair: ")

seqpair = list(map(int, seqpair.split()))

if seqpair > 2:
    print (seqpair)
else:
    print ('Invalid number')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu fiz dessa forma:

```py
number = int(input('Digite um número: '))

if(number >= 2):
  # O range(0, numer + 1, 2) cria um objeto do tipo range.
  # Iniciando com 0 indo até o number + 1, pulando de 2 em 2.
  # Como 0 é par e está com saltos de 2 os numeros sempre serão par.

  # O list(range(0, number + 1, 2)) converte o objeto range gerado para um objeto list.
  list_numbers = list(range(0, number + 1, 2))

  print(list_numbers)  
else:  
  print('Invalid number')
```

Comment: **lista = list(range(0, numero + 1, 2))** me explica essa parte do código?

Comment: @AlexFeliciano O range(0, number + 1, 2) significa que ele vai criar um objeto range iniciando do 0 até number + 1 pulando de 2 em 2, ai o range é convertido em um list e atribuído a sua variável lista

Comment: Boa solução, mas ai tb tem uma iteração do tipo list comprehension, com o adicional do do custo do `if`

Comment: @AlexFeliciano comentei o código para facilitar a explicação

Comment: @Sidon como assim custo adicional do if? se eu não utilizei nenhum if

Comment: `if number>2` linha adicional eu quis dizer. Na verdade um bloco adicional

Comment: @Sidon assim, ta especificado na pergunta do Alex que se caso o número seja menor que 2 deve imprimir Invalid number

Comment: É verdade @ViniciusFernandes comi bola, Sorry! :-)

Answer (score 4):

Como curiosidade, veja outra forma de resolver este problema utilizando `filter` e `lambda`

```
lista = list(range(1,1+int(input('Digite o numero: '))))
# Suponha que a pessoa digitou 20.
print(lista)
#[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]

pares = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, lista))
print(pares)
#[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade de *list comprehension* x => x? Não bastaria fazer `lista = range(...)`?

Comment: Obrigado pela dica da função `filter()`

Comment: Você tem razão Anderson, editei a resposta. Por nada Alex

Answer (score 3):

[Assim](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/odd-sequence):

**Usando list comprehension:**

```
number = int(input('digite o numero: '))
lst= [n for n in range(number+1) if n%2==0]
print('','list comprehension:',lst, sep='\n')
```

**Usando o laço `for`:**

```
# usando for
lst = []
for n in range(number+1):
    if n%2==0:
        lst.append(n)

print('','Usando for:',lst, sep='\n')
```

Entrada: `30`

Saída:

```
Usando list comprehension:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]

Usando for:
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30]
```

[Rode o codigo no repl.it.](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/odd-sequence)

Comment: Poderia mostrar o código sem usar **loop**?

Comment: A primeira opcao não usa loop (list comprehension), usa somente uma linha, aliás, até usa, mas não explicitamente.

Comment: Acho que não @Sidon, veja que tem um for no (list comprehension)

Comment: Verdade, mas não tenho certeza se nesse caso o for pode ser considerado loop, talvez uma iteração. :-)

Comment: nunca tinha visto **list comprehension** e o professor da faculdade que faço também não sabe pois ele está vendo Python agora nesse semestre juntos com os alunos rsrsrs.

Comment: List comprehensio a primeira vista parece complicado, mas depois que vc usar algumas vezes vai querer usar sempre, e o pior que nunca vai querer usar lambda. :-)

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss verdade, lembro que estava extrapolando no testes e encontrei as duas solucoes: `n<=number` ou `number+1` mas acabei implementando as duas. Fail!  [Editado]